# Can't run simple Visual Studio 2013 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to install `OpenCV 2411` in `Visual Studio 2013`, but i receive an error when I try to build the project. The error says: `LINK1104: cant open file opencv_core2411.obj`

I then decided to check that if I created a simple C++ example without the `OpenCV 2411` library and see if i will receive an output. I created a new project to print only the word '*hello*', but upon building the project I received the same error message mentioned before: `LINK1104: cant open file opencv_core2411.obj` despite for that new project that should display 'Hello'; I have not imported the Opencv 2411 libraries.

Why am I receiving that error while the project is never relevant to `OpenCV 2411` library?

Comment: Did you create a completely new project when attempting a `Hello, World!` program? It sounds as if you've left some library dependencies in the configuration. :-)

Comment: yes i have created a cmopletely new project to print a simple word, abut at run time i receive the above ststed error....can u please tell me how to correct it..i was looking for a solution in google but even after following a tutorila aboout how to display a simpple word, i receive the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Close and reopen Visual Studio.
2. Select File -> New Project -> Visual C++ -> Empty Project
3. Right click source files and select -> Add -> New Item...
4. Select C++ File (.cpp) and give it a name, i.e. `main.cpp`
5. Paste in the "Hello" code (at the bottom of answer)
6. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to Start Debugging

---

**Hello Code:**

```
   #include <iostream>  
   int main(){ std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl; return 0; }
```

Comment: i tried it, but the same error again, i do not know why the linker\compiler still try to run opencv_core2411.obj